# Sightly - accessing jcr:content values

Tags: aem

From a components JavaScript, how do I access values inside jcr:content for the containing page?

I was expecting pageProperties to help but it seems not ... It gives me "title" but other things (custom values for the page, for example) it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html
There are various examples on how to read content with JS in CQ 5.6.1.
If it still doesn't work, you might want to post your code snippet so we can better help you find the problem.